# Error "unauthorized_client" while authenticating my Azure registered app using Microsoft Account

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Instead of taking me to the login screen it is showing the error as below while setting up my app and AD in the Azure portal as per the steps provided here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app

> We're unable to complete your request
>   unauthorized_client: The client does not exist or is not enabled for consumers. If you are the application developer, configure a new application through the App Registrations in the Azure Portal at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To allow Microsoft Account, you must choose `Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)` when you register the application,.

[image]

Comment: This option fixed this problem for me, even though it would make sense that the other options should work as well.